# Code is slower on Linux as compared to Windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, optimization

After modifying my C code, (written originally for Windows and compiled under VS 2008), I ran it on Linux. To my  surprise it is now at least 10 times slower than windows version.

Using Profiler tools I figured out that the following function is consuming most of the time spent in the application:

```
/* advance by n bits */

void Flush_Buffer(N)
int N;
{
 int Incnt;


 ld->Bfr <<= N;

Incnt = ld->Incnt -= N;

if (Incnt <= 24)
{
if (System_Stream_Flag && (ld->Rdptr >= ld->Rdmax-4))
{
do
{
if (ld->Rdptr >= ld->Rdmax)
      Next_Packet();
    ld->Bfr |= Get_Byte() << (24 - Incnt);
    Incnt += 8;
  }
  while (Incnt <= 24);
}
else if (ld->Rdptr < ld->Rdbfr+2044)
{
  do
  {
    ld->Bfr |= *ld->Rdptr++ << (24 - Incnt);
    Incnt += 8;
  }
  while (Incnt <= 24);
}
else
{
  do
  {
    if (ld->Rdptr >= ld->Rdbfr+2048)
      Fill_Buffer();
    ld->Bfr |= *ld->Rdptr++ << (24 - Incnt);
    Incnt += 8;
  }
  while (Incnt <= 24);
}
ld->Incnt = Incnt;
}

}
```

This function was taking negligible time on windows. on Linux it is taking taking close to 14 sec. What wrong I have committed here?

There are no system calls here so this code section should be independent of OS specific calls and thus should run in identical time.

(My Guess: This function is being called multiple times, so may be the profiler is accumulating the time of all the calls too. In such a case I think one of the issues might be that the function is not getting its input parameter quickly as compared to windows case.  )

What wrong I have committed here?  Any guess?

Rgrds,

H

Comment: This question is meaningless unless you specify at least (1) the compiler options you used, and (2) how you're measuring the time spent.

Comment: How did you compile your code (what compiler, what options, (what warning level))?

Comment: Another guess is , may be since data type size is different on the two  machines, I might  be ending up doing more computations at low level on Linux. May be  I should cross check that the size of the data types are matching on the two system. Any idea I am going in the right direction?

Comment: No, you're going in the wrong direction by asking a question, omitting all the relevant information, and then ignoring requests to provide it.

Comment: Did you use optimisation on Linux? Option `-O[1|2|3]` for the `gcc` compiler?

Comment: Ok, It was somewhat like this (note O3):  gcc -g filename.c -o3 foldeTv libmpeg2.a ... ....gthread-2.0

Comment: What profiler are you using? If it's gprof (`gcc -pg`) then there's your problem; gprof makes tiny functions easily ten times slower. You need a profiler that doesn't alter the behavior of the program.

Comment: I used Valgrind for profiling

Comment: Valgrind isn't a profiler. It's a memory debugger. (It also has other tools: Helgrind, a thread debugger; Massif, a heap profiler; and Cachegrind, a cache profiler. None of them are *timers*.)

Comment: @gpuguy: Valgrind let's your app run up to 50times slower ...; and it's **-O3** not -o3 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to annotate all code paths in your code with counters. At the end of the program, each counter will contain information about how many times the code path has been executed. Comparing these numbers line-by-line between the Windows version and the Linux version *may* reveal that the program is following different code paths. Depending on the nature of the code paths, the differences *may* be able to explain why the Linux version is slower than the Windows version.

```
int count[100];

// Call this function at the end of program 
void PrintCounts() {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<100; i++) printf("%d\n", count[i]);
}

void Flush_Buffer(int N) {
  int Incnt;

  ld->Bfr <<= N;

  Incnt = ld->Incnt -= N;

  if (Incnt <= 24) {
    count[0]++;
    if (System_Stream_Flag && (ld->Rdptr >= ld->Rdmax-4)) {
      count[1]++;
      do {
         count[2]++;
         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a note than an answer, but it doesn't quite fit into a comment, so I hope you won't hold this against me.

The term "profiling" has several related, but different meanings. In an abstract context it means "measuring" your program, usually with respect to certain runtime data. However, it's not the same as simply "timing" your program. Timing is one form of profiling, but there are many others.

For example, suppose you're unsure whether some data structure should be a `std::set` (a tree) or a `std::unordered_set` (a hash table). There isn't a universal answer, since it depends on what you use it for and what data you're processing. It is entirely possible that you *cannot* know the right answer until you specify the actual, real-world data that you're going to use. In that case, "profile and decide" means that you make two versions of your program, run them both against your real data, and measure the runtime. The faster one is probably the one you want.

On the other hand, GCC has a tool that's called "profiler" which serves a very different purpose. It's an execution path profiler, if you will, which tells you where (i.e. in which function) your program spends most of its time. If you have a complex algorithm with lots of subroutines, you may not know which ones are the important ones, and again this may actually depend on your real-world input. In that case, the profiler can help you determined which functions are called the most *given your input data*, and you can concentrate optimisation efforts on those functions. Now "profile before optimising" means that you need to determine the priorities before getting to work.

That said, for the comparison you have in mind, you must not use the GCC profiler. Rather, compile on both platforms with all optimisations enabled and under release conditions, and then measure the runtime on the same set of input data.

Comment: I would recommend never using the gcc profiler. For large functions the overhead is small, but for small functions the time spent in the function is dominated by profiling overhead. This means that well-factored programs perform horribly (and give horribly skewed profiling results) with the gcc profiler. Then of course there are all sorts of issues with the results being distorted by selective inlining. If you want to measure where time is spent in your program, the only viable method is one that involves periodic sampling of the instruction pointer and stack, e.g. oprofile.